# How to create a third vector from two existing vectors with looping and indexing?

Tags: python, loops, vector, indexing, conditional-statements

I have two vectors (`a`, `b`) and want to create a third one (`c`) from these two. They all should have the same length. If there is a zero (0) in the vector `a`, the value of the vector `b` with this index, where `a` is zero, should be summed with the next values until the value in the vector `a` is eleven (11) and then storage the sum of this values in the vector `c`. The rest of the values of `c` should be zero (0).

```
a=[0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11]
b=[1.1, 1.1, 9, 9, 9, 6.6, 6.6, 9]
```

So the vector `c` should look like:

```
c=[0, 2.2, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 31.2]
```

I create the next code and it works almost for this case except for the last value (it comes as output for the last value `15.6`). And I also need something with more efficient, then it could happen that the vector `a` has more than 3 zeros after each other.

```
for w in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[w]==0 and a[w+1]!=0:
        c[w+1]=b[w]+b[w+1]

    elif a[w]==0 and a[w+1]==0 and a[w+2]!=0:
        c[w+2]=b[w]+b[w+1]+b[w+2]

    elif a[w]==0 and a[w+1]==0 and a[w+2]==0:
        c[w+3]=b[w]+b[w+1]+b[w+2]+b[w+3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we can loop over both `a` and `b` at the same time by using `zip`

We then just need to sum the cumulated values from `b` until the value in `a` is `11`, when we get `11` then we write the cumulated value and reset it, otherwise write a `0`

```
a = [0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11]
b = [1.1, 1.1, 9, 9, 9, 6.6, 6.6, 9]
culm = 0
result = []
for a_val, b_val in zip(a, b):
    culm += b_val
    if a_val == 11:
        result.append(culm)
        culm = 0
    else:
        result.append(0)

print(result) # [0, 2.2, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 31.2]
```